# Cyclic group generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

My question is: Can you find a cyclic group with n generators?

I know that zero (or any other identity element for that matter) is included, so there would be for $Z_n$ at most n-1 generators. However, is it possible to say that $Z_{n+1}$ could provide n generators?

Any help would be much appreciated! If you wouldn't mind, I would appreciate it if you provide enough detail to really help me understand so I can learn. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A cyclic group by definition only *needs* one generator. In general, there are exactly $\varphi(n)$ elements in a cyclic group of order $n$ which generate the entire group ($\varphi$ is the Euler phi function)

Comment: The question was not about how many generators do you need, for example I could simple say <0> which is trivially cyclic with one generator of zero. Instead I am asking if you could find a a cyclic group with n generators. Like 2 generators or four

Comment: Let me refrain from using the word generators for now: are you asking for which $n$ does there exist a cyclic group that has exactly $n$ elements which generate the group? If so, then the answer is: precisely the $n$ which occur as values of the Euler phi function

Comment: I apologize if my wording is funny. I am asking if you could find me a group with x generators, what would it be? For example,if I asked find a cyclic group with exactly two generators, I would say Z because it has generators 1 and -1. Now, by the same token, what cyclic group would have n generators?

Comment: I think I understand your question now. Note that the answer is not unique, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ also has exactly $2$ generators $1$ and $-1$. Also, e.g. there is no cyclic group with exactly $3$ generators

Answer (score 6):

For the trivial group, and the group with two elements, there is one generator.  So the answer to your question is yes if $n=1$.

For cyclic groups of order larger than $2$, if $x$ is a generator, then $x^{-1}$ is also a generator, and $x\ne x^{-1}$ else $x$ has order $1$ or $2$ (contradiction).  Hence, in this case, generators come in pairs and hence there must be an even number of them.  So the answer to your question is no if $n>1$ and $n$ is odd.

If $n$ is even, then as the comments note, a cyclic group of order $m$ has $\varphi(m)$ generators, so we need to find some $m$ such that $\varphi(m)=n$.  However, it is not always the case that such $m$ exists.  Even $n$ that are not equal to $\varphi(m)$ for some $m$ are called "non-totients" and are listed in [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A005277).  So finally, the answer to your question is no if $n$ is even and a non-totient, and yes if $n=\varphi(m)$ for some $m$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What does the little squiggly(m) stand for?

Comment: @BillyThorton: $\varphi(m)$ denotes the Euler-phi function.  Its value is equal to $|\{a\in\mathbb{Z}\mid 1\le a<m,\;(a,m)=1\}|$.  That is, count the number of numbers in the list $1,\ldots,m-1$ that are coprime to $m$.

Comment: Sorry to be asking so many years later, but could you further explain why if $x$ is a generator then $x^{-1}$ is a generator and why $x\ne x^{-1}$?